# Interface role in Dependency Injection

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have the data access layer below

```
 public class UserDataAccess
{
    private IDbConnection db;
    public UserDataAccess(IConfiguration conf)
    {
        this.db = new SqlConnection(conf.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
    }
}
```

In my controller I have

```
public class AccessController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserDataAccess userDb;

    public AccessController(UserDataAccess dba)
    {
        userDb = dba;
    }
}
```

This generates a runtime error. However When I user an interface for my Data access layer and use that for dependency injection in my controller, everything works out. Are we always supposed to use interfaces for dependency injection?
Error is

```
 Unable to resolve service for type 'Repository.UserDataAccess' while attempting to activate 'Controllers.AccessController'.
```

and `Repository.UserDataAccess` is the data access layer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Register the `UserDataAccess` class with the service container:

```
public void ConfigureServices( IServiceCollection services )
{
    services.AddScoped<UserDataAccess>(); // this call depends on desired liftime/scope
    ...
}
```

It's a better practice to use interfaces, however.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0